# Get user public profile link via get_users() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for a long time now to find how to get the user's link to his public profile page (author.php) via the function `get_users()` that i am using to display all the users registered on the site. I display the users with a `foreach` loop.

Do you guys know if there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, here is the solution :

```
foreach ($membres as $membre) {
    $membre_url = get_author_posts_url($membre->id);
}
```